# Freeform Pro Plugin Mailchimp integration

Tags: plugin-freeform

Got issues with Freeform Pro Plugin, no matter what settings I set on status in the plugin the subscriber goes right into the list on Mailchimp even though status is set to 'pending' on plugin both at default and form setting level.No double opt-in verification.

Any ideas guys?

Plus unrelated, the user when sends also gets a notification of what they have sent, we don't want this. And if we ever did, we would want a custom template for it. any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. We needed to send a contact information form to MailChimp only if the person opted in to receive e-mails. However, the information would always be sent even if the opt-in box was left unchecked. No idea why. I ended up hiding the opt-in box and then added a "yes or no" field that conveyed whether or not the user wanted to receive e-mails. Hope that help and makes sense!